# How to get project id in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I have activated Google Cloud Storage on my Gmail account, then created a new Project. As far as I see, and read from tutorials (https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples), Client Secrets (client_secrets.json) are related to Projects, not to my account.

Now, while using Java API, there is a way to receive the list of buckets,

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list

Though it asks me to enter the project identifier as parameter.

I checked API documentation, the download client secrets file (client_secrets.json), and Java methods, though nothing is providing me the "Project Identifier" that is related to authenticated client secret's project.

Is there any method to find out on which project I am actively authenticated? I wouldn't want programme user to remember each project's identifier every time they authenticate in Java programme. The client secrets file is already related to a single project.

---

Extra Information:
Currently I developed a GUI Java application.
By using Open File Dialog, user selects the downloaded "client_secrets.json" file.
Then I use that example provided "authorise" method to get `Credentials` and `Storage` objects.

After this, I want to list all buckets those are available in current project programmatically. (Current Project = The client_secrets.json is downloaded from a specific project.). But API requires me to enter the project name which doesn't seem to get programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to see it in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project). Click on a project, and at the top it will tell you the project ID.

(If you were looking for a way of getting this programmatically, please clarify this in your question - it's not clear what information you "have in your hand" when you want to get the project ID... or whether you're expecting your users to create their own projects.)

Comment: Yes, it is possible to see it in Developer Console. I want users to use Java client application. I added extra information to the question.

Comment: @tcak: It's still not clear to me how many projects are involved here... are your users creating their own Google projects?

Comment: User goes to Developer Console. Creates a new project (Project X). From that project, downloads client_secrets.json file. Opens Java client application. Authorises the application with that json file. That application lists Project X's bucket list.

Comment: @tcak: Right. While it looks like the client secrets contains the project *number* as part of one value, I wouldn't personally try to use that to get back to the project ID. I would currently just ask users to copy/paste the project ID at the same time as they download the client secrets file. If they're going to do this multiple times, you could create a file which combines the two

Comment: Hmm. In case another person has any idea about getting project id, I will wait. Anyway, I hope my understanding about client_secrets.json is correct. Each project has a different client_secrets.json file, right?

Comment: @tcak: I believe so. I should know more about this, to be honest, as a Googler - but I haven't looked at it as much as you might expect.

Comment: Understood. Well, if each project has a specific client_secret, then API shouldn't be asking for project id, and query it from database. Either there is design mistake in the system, or forward thinking plan.

Comment: @tcak: No, I don't think I'd count that as a design mistake. A client secret is *one* way of authenticating, but there may be others - either now or in the future. Logically, you're asking for the resources for a specific project - so it makes sense to require that you specify which project you're interested in.

Answer (score 4):

Run

```
gsutil ls -L -b gs://<bucket-name>
```

to get the bucket info, you can find the project number from the output. Then you could run

```
gcloud projects list --filter "PROJECT_NUMBER=<project-number>"
```

to find out the project ID.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `jq`:

```sh
project_number=$(gsutil acl get gs://<bucket> | jq ".[0].projectTeam.projectNumber")
gcloud projects list --filter "PROJECT_NUMBER=$project_number"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: The current version of the json-file (used for authentication) contains the ProjectId.

The suggested way is to create a "service account key" json file, like so: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#creating_a_service_account (p12 is only there for backward-compatibility)

Thus, you can read it from the json file like so: (C# Code, but Java Code should be very close) (Note: static constructor is called before first instantiation of class)

```
    public class YourClass
    {
        private static readonly string GoogleProjectId;

        static YourClass()
        {
            var GoogleAutFilePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
            var GContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(File.ReadAllText(GoogleAutFilePath));
            GoogleProjectId = GContent["project_id"].ToString();
        }
    }
```